# What Event to Delegate by Javascript function when I jump to my bookmarked id using link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link , which has a href of "#myid", which is h1 (let say). I want some javascript function to get run when my h1 is focused i.e. 'jumped to' by link. I tried onfocus() but its not working. I am more a middle & data tier developer, so finding a bit weird working in deep with front end languages :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `hashchange` event you can listen for on `window`:

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', (e) => {
  console.log(e.newURL);
});
```

```css
.padding {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#myid">click</a>
<div class="padding"></div>
<div id="myid">myid<br>myid</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run javascript function while **hover or focus** by using jquery.  Please refer the code below.

```js
$( "h1" ).hover(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a sample H1</h1>
```

**Focus function is used for input field**.you can only handle focus for h1 using tab index.

```
$( "h1" ).focus(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});
```